# Boxed rectangles or squares for 4 submatrix into a matrix

Tags: errors, matrices, mathtools, tikz-matrix, nicematrix

I have taken this code from the documentation of `nicematrix` package to the pag. 44/208 version 5.12 of at the date of 2021/03/10.

[image]

1. In the meantime I have this error of compilation: why? (I have the recent updating MikTeX on OS W7-32bit).

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
   \usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
   \begin{document}
   $\begin{pNiceMatrix}[margin,create-medium-nodes]
   \Block{3-3}<\Large>{A} & & & 0 \\
   & \hspace*{1cm} & & \Vdots \\
   & & & 0 \\
   0 & \Cdots& 0 & 0
   \CodeAfter
   \tikz \node [highlight = (1-1-block-medium)] {} ;
   \end{pNiceMatrix}$
   \end{document}
   ```

   > ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/highlight', to which you passed '(1-1-block-medium)', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
   > Type  H   for immediate help.  ...
   > l.12 \end{pNiceMatrix}
   > $
   > ?
2. If I had to draw a matrix with four boxed rectangles or squares where inside are the elements of the matrix. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key `highlight` is defined  previously in the document (documentation of `nicematrix`).

---

For the construction you want, consider first the following matrix.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\(\begin{pNiceArray}{cc|cc}
\frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{A^2+B^2} & \frac{2ab}{a+b} & A^2+B^2 & \frac{a^2+b^2}{2} \\
0 & \frac{a^2+b^2}{2} & \frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{A^2+B^2} & \frac{2ab}{a+b} \\
\hline
2A^2+2B^2 & 0 & \frac{2ab}{a+b} & \frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{A^2+B^2}  \\
\frac{2ab}{a+b} & \frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{A^2+B^2} & 0 & \frac{a^2+b^2}{2} \\
\end{pNiceArray}\)
\end{document}
```

[image: First matrix]

Before drawing frames, you have to add space. For the vertical space, I use some `\vskip` in `\noalign`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
$\begin{pNiceArray}{cc|cc}[margin=2pt]
\noalign{\vskip\smallskipamount}
\frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{A^2+B^2} & \frac{2ab}{a+b} & A^2+B^2 & \frac{a^2+b^2}{2} \\
0 & \frac{a^2+b^2}{2} & \frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{A^2+B^2} & \frac{2ab}{a+b} \\[4pt]
\hline
\noalign{\vskip4pt}
2A^2+2B^2 & 0 & \frac{2ab}{a+b} & \frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{A^2+B^2}  \\
\frac{2ab}{a+b} & \frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{A^2+B^2} & 0 & \frac{a^2+b^2}{2} \\
\noalign{\vskip\smallskipamount}
\end{pNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Second matrix]

You can now draw the frames with Tikz in the `\CodeAfter`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{highlight/.style={rectangle,
                           draw=blue,
                           rounded corners = 0.5 mm, 
                           inner sep=1pt,
                           fit=#1}}
$\begin{pNiceArray}{cc|cc}[margin=2pt]
\noalign{\vskip\smallskipamount}
\frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{A^2+B^2} & \frac{2ab}{a+b} & A^2+B^2 & \frac{a^2+b^2}{2} \\
0 & \frac{a^2+b^2}{2} & \frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{A^2+B^2} & \frac{2ab}{a+b} \\[4pt]
\hline
\noalign{\vskip4pt}
2A^2+2B^2 & 0 & \frac{2ab}{a+b} & \frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{A^2+B^2}  \\
\frac{2ab}{a+b} & \frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{A^2+B^2} & 0 & \frac{a^2+b^2}{2} \\
\noalign{\vskip\smallskipamount}
\CodeAfter
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [highlight=(1-1)(1-2)(2-1)(2-2)] {} ; 
\node [highlight=(1-3)(1-4)(2-3)(2-4)] {} ; 
\node [highlight=(3-1)(3-2)(4-1)(4-2)] {} ;
\node [highlight=(3-3)(3-4)(4-3)(4-4)] {} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{pNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Third matrix]

Maybe you want homogeneity for the four blue frames. In that case, you should use the `medium` nodes (created by `nicematrix`).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{highlight/.style={rectangle,
                           draw=blue,
                           rounded corners = 0.5 mm, 
                           inner sep=1pt,
                           fit=#1}}
$\begin{pNiceArray}{cc|cc}[margin=2pt,create-medium-nodes]
\noalign{\vskip\smallskipamount}
\frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{A^2+B^2} & \frac{2ab}{a+b} & A^2+B^2 & \frac{a^2+b^2}{2} \\
0 & \frac{a^2+b^2}{2} & \frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{A^2+B^2} & \frac{2ab}{a+b} \\[4pt]
\hline
\noalign{\vskip4pt}
2A^2+2B^2 & 0 & \frac{2ab}{a+b} & \frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{A^2+B^2}  \\
\frac{2ab}{a+b} & \frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{A^2+B^2} & 0 & \frac{a^2+b^2}{2} \\
\noalign{\vskip\smallskipamount}
\CodeAfter
\begin{tikzpicture}[name suffix = -medium]
\node [highlight=(1-1)(1-2)(2-1)(2-2)] {} ; 
\node [highlight=(1-3)(1-4)(2-3)(2-4)] {} ; 
\node [highlight=(3-1)(3-2)(4-1)(4-2)] {} ;
\node [highlight=(3-3)(3-4)(4-3)(4-4)] {} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{pNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Fourth matrix]

Comment: Thank you very very very much for your exhaustive explanation and for your precious contribute.